# How do I recover CiviGrant Component?

Tags: issues, civigrant

I disabled, and re-enabled CiviGrant and now I can no longer access it.  I **tried to rebuild the menus** and actually **reproduced this on the demo** [site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1): Its not just the Grant and Grant Admin menus.  if i try to use a link I get access denied.  **The grant component is working at the API level.**
Any suggestions on how to recover the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into your CMS permissions and check that your role has all the CiviGrant permissions. They are not automatically granted when you enable the component (though it is a little surprising that they would be revoked upon disabling it).

You also might try logging out and then in again.

Comment: You are right! It was a strange permission issue as I had 2 roles one with and the other without permission and YES, it appears there is a bug that when you enable/disable it resets the drupal permission.  working now.  thanks.

Comment: CRM-16937 - disable/enable of Grants resets Drupal Permission

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue but so far hasn't risen to the top of anyone's to-do list. Patches from the community would be more than welcome.

See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-9659